# SQL - Using query with date parameters with IN used for a sub-query

Tags: mysql

I have the following query which is returning nothing:

```
SELECT e.`value`, e.`machine_id`, e.`date_recorded` 
from engine_hours e 
where e.`date_recorded` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 32 DAY 
  AND e.`date_recorded` <= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY 
  AND e.`machine_id` IN (SELECT m.id FROM  `machines` m WHERE m.`title` =  'ABC-123')
```

When I break the query and sub-query into two independent queries they work fine

**Question:**
How can I use what the sub-query returns to the main query, alongside the date boundaries in the WHERE section of the main query.

---

**Clarification & Better Explanation:**
I get no errors.

When I run the sub-query as a query of its own ie:

```
SELECT m.id FROM  `machines` m WHERE m.`title` =  'ABC-123'
```

it returns `1234` which is correct. And when I use this returned value `1234` in the main query ie:

```
SELECT e.`value`, e.`machine_id`, e.`date_recorded` 
from engine_hours e 
where e.`date_recorded` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 32 DAY 
  AND e.`date_recorded` <= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY 
  AND e.`machine_id = '1234'
```

I get the data I am after. 
I can't seem to understand what I am doing wrong.

---

**Explaining the dates:**

I want to get the data starting from 32 days ago till 2 days ago:

```
where e.`date_recorded` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 32 DAY 
AND e.`date_recorded` <= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY
```

ie `now` is 2019-03-06, 32 days ago (`NOW() - INTERVAL 32 DAY`) will be **2019-02-02** 
and similarly 2 days ago will be **2019-03-04**.

The information I want should be greater than or equal to (`>=`) **2019-02-02**  and less then or equal to (`<=`) **2019-03-04**.

Comment: is there any error?

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: @andronicus no error. Just doesnt return anything.. when i try the subquery as a query and use the output of it on thr main query it returns what I want..

Comment: For the record, there was some confusion with the dates and hence the explanation

Comment: So many wasted words. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

Use join

```
SELECT e.`value`, e.`machine_id`, e.`date_recorded`,m.id
from engine_hours e join `machines` m on e.`machine_id`=m.id
where e.`date_recorded` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 32 DAY 
  AND e.`date_recorded` <= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY 
  and m.`title` =  'ABC-123'
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**

I've just tried it myself, it's working fine. Each query individually is correct (syntax & logic). Both queries together is also correct (syntax & logic).

So it's either:

- The `machine_id` in the targeted rows in `engine_hours` is different than `1234`.
- The `date_recorded` in the targeted rows in `engine_hours` is not of the date range desired.
- The query you posted in StackOverflow is slightly different than the one you have in your source code.
- Maybe you're including the database name in the query. If so, make sure you're targeting the correct database name.

I suggest you delete the entire query in your source code and re-write it again. You probably have some hidden character(s), wrong operator used, or alike.

Comment: `e.date_recorded <= NOW() + INTERVAL 32 DAY` should be `e.date_recorded <= NOW() - INTERVAL 32 DAY` ie _take away 32 days away from now_ -  to clarify - i just want the data returned from 32 days ago  till 2 days ago.

Comment: thanks I'll try again - would you have an alternative query that would yield the same output?

Comment: @3kstc you can try the query suggested by **fa06**, but your query is totally valid